# Recursively copy a child directory to the parent in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

I need to recursively move the contents of a sub-folder to a parent folder in google cloud storage.  This code works for moving a single file from sub-folder to the parent.

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

source_path = Path(parent_dir, sub_folder, filename).as_posix()
source_blob = bucket.blob(source_path)

dest_path = Path(parent_dir, filename).as_posix()
bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, bucket, dest_path)
```

but I don't know how to properly format the command because if my dest_path is "parent_dir", I get the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/parent_dir%2Fsubfolder/copyTo/b/geo-storage/o/parent_dir?prettyPrint=false: No such object: geo-storage/parent_dir/subfolder
```

Note: This works for recursive copy with gsutils but I would prefer to use the blob object:

```
os.system(f"gsutil cp -r gs://bucket/parent_dir/subfolder/* gs://bucket/parent_dir")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCS does not have the concept of "directory" - just a flat namespace of objects. You can have an object named "foo/a.txt" and "foo/b.txt", but there is not actual thing representing "foo/" - its' just a prefix on the object names.

`gsutil` uses prefixes on the object names to pretend directories exist, but under the hood it is really just acting on all the individual objects with that prefix.

You need to do the same, with a copy for each object:

```py
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

for source_blob in client.list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME, prefix="old/prefix/"):
   dest_name = source_blob.name.replace("old/prefix/", "new/prefix/")
   # do these in parallel for more speed
   bucket.copy_blob(source_blob, bucket, new_name=dest_name)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to parallelize the for loop?

Comment: The only way built-in to the client lib is batching -- wrap the for loop in `with client.batch():` and it will batch up requests. You might need to use a separate client for the list_blobs calls then, so that it doesn't try and batch the list (and so hang).  Other than that you can use python's built in parallelization tools like threads or asyncio.

Comment: What is object?  is that source_blob?

Comment: yes, edited to fix